# Using a list as argument names for lambda scheme/racket

Tags: scheme, racket, lambda, let, evaluator

I'm working on a scheme evaluator in scheme. I need to implement let, I have parsed so that I have variable names, values to input and the body of the function. I need to return a lambda function using the parsed information and as such I have the following code:

```
(define (eval-let exp env)
  ((lambda (let-variables (let-bindings exp)) (let-body exp)) (let-exp (let-bindings exp))))
```

(let-variables (let-bindings exp)) evaluates to a list of variable names (ex: '(x y)), so I'm basically evaluating to this:

```
((lambda '(x y) (* x y)) '(2 3))
```

The scheme interpreter simple says: #%plain-lambda: not an identifier in: (let-bindings exp) which I'm guessing is because it wants a set of identifiers, not a list of values.

How do I turn my list of values into a set of identifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement a `let` expression in your own interpreter first you have to transform it into a `lambda` application, something similar to this (procedure names should be self-explanatory):

```
(define (let->combination exp)
  (let* ((bindings (let-bindings exp))
         (body     (let-body exp))
         (exps     (bindings-all-exps bindings))
         (lambda   (make-lambda (bindings-all-vars bindings) body)))
    (make-application lambda exps)))

(define (make-lambda parameters body)
  (list* 'lambda parameters body))

(define (make-application proc . args)
  (cond ((null? args) (list proc))
        ((list? (car args)) (cons proc (car args)))
        (else (cons proc args))))
```

And *after* the syntax transformation has been performed you can proceed to evaluate it:

```
(eval (let->combination exp) env)
```

What I'm trying to point out is that you shouldn't try to evaluate it directly. Also be careful, the code you're generating has a couple of incorrect quotes:

```
((lambda '(x y) (* x y)) '(2 3))
         ^               ^
       here            here
```

It should look like this instead:

```
((lambda (x y) (* x y)) 2 3)
```

Comment: The "trying to evaluate directly" is what got on track. I forgot I had an apply procedure already that basically takes in this stuff as lists. Thanks!

Comment: Great! it was my pleasure :)